# radio boxes are not setting attribute checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I guess kind of a silly question here. I have created a .html file on my desktop outside of fiddle (so please don't test it in fiddle but just create a .html file on your computer to test this). in the file I JUST have 3 radio buttons and jquery attached. However, boxes never work right as checked or clicked attribute never gets set on them and literally they don't alternate when checked on. What am I missing here?

```
<html>
<head>      
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="well" value="well" />1 - Very well<br />
    <input type="radio" name="little" value="little" />2 - A little<br />
    <input type="radio" name="not" value="not" />3 - Not at all<br />
</body>
```

Comment: Of course, the jQuery library serves no purpose as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radio buttons don't know they're related. The name attribute should be the same, while the value can be changed for each.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="well" />1 - Very well<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="little" />2 - A little<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="not" />3 - Not at all<br />
```

Comment: ha i told you stupid question.. i had a major brain freeze.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> However, boxes never work right as checked or clicked attribute never gets set on them

None of the code you've supplied will set the `checked` attribute.

You need to actually set it, to set it:

```
 <input type="radio" name="well" value="well" checked>
```

Note: Browsers remember the state of forms when refreshing the page. If you are testing by modifying the HTML and then clicking the refresh button, you may not see any effect. Click the address bar and press enter to avoid this problem.

There is no `clicked` attribute for the `input` element.

> they don't alternate when checked on

They have different `name` attribute values. To be part of the same radio group, each radio button must share the same name.

You have three groups, each with one member.

Comment: thank you i knew i was missing something very stupid.

Answer (score -1):

In order for them to be mutually exclusive (so that when you select one, it deselects any others) all of the radio elements have to have the same name.  Change your code like so and it will work:

```
<html>
<head>      
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="well" />1 - Very well<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="little" />2 - A little<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="not" />3 - Not at all<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, if you wrap each `input` element inside a `label`, you can click on each description to select that option as well.